# Can we use ngRoute and ui.router together in angularJS app.js?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Previously, I was using `ngRoute` in my main controller. I have to create child view functionality and it is only achieved by `UI-Router`. please suggest?

Comment: You can, as @Suneet suggests -- but you should probably just migrate your application to uiRouter instead of using both.

Comment: @Martin: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use both.

```
var myModule = angular.module("myModule", ["ui.router", "ngRoute"]);
```

Comment: Can you use both simultaneously like <body ng-view ui-view ></body> ?

Comment: No, the two directives will compete for transclusion on the body. Depending on your styling, you could try putting one after the other (i.e., <body><div ng-view></div><div ui-view></div></body>).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `ngRoute`/`angular-route` (`$routeProvider`) and `ui-router` (`$stateProvider`) together (in particular, the second inside of the first). Check [this repo's master](https://github.com/loenko/ng-routing) to find the example. 
In a couple of words, the `ui-router` in this case will have the possibility to provide navigation and nested states/views inside of "`ng-view`-provided space".
I have answered almost the same question with more details and pros/cons [at Quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-ngRoute-with-a-UI-Router-in-Angular)